# How to alias or redirect dynamic url to subdomain

Tags: php, apache, redirect, server

I have this url (dynamic URL, not a folder)
http://domain.com/product/create

I want it to 
http://create.domain.com/

Because cloudflare won't allow uploads more than 100MB, so I've to make it subdomain (so cloudflare will not makes limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set an A record in your DNS Settings

Assuming your domain is `domain.com`:

[image: screenshot]

with the IP address of your server should do. You'll then probably have to set up [an Apache Virtual Host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) that looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName create.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/create/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: /var/www/create/ >> But this is not folder, its dynamic URL.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming the IP address you enter in your DNS records points to the server hosting your `create` files. The Apache Virtual Host should therefore be created on that server with the `DocumentRoot` referring to the local `create` folder.